# Как вызвать метод контроллера в приложении на ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

У меня есть контроллер

```
public class GoodsSortController : Controller
{
    // GET: Sort
    private IGoodRepository rep;

    public GoodsSortController(IGoodRepository repository)
    {
        rep = repository;
    }
    
    public PartialViewResult Sort(string fieldsort = "id", string sorttype = "asc")
    {
        IEnumerable<Good> goods = rep.Goods;
        switch (fieldsort)
        {
            case "id":
                {
                    if (sorttype == "asc")
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderBy(good => good.GoodID);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderByDescending(good => good.GoodID);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case "name":
                {
                    if (sorttype == "asc")
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderBy(good => good.Name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderByDescending(good => good.Name);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case "price":
                {
                    if (sorttype == "asc")
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderBy(good => good.Price);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderByDescending(good => good.Price);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case "views":
                {
                    if (sorttype == "asc")
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderBy(good => good.Views);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderByDescending(good => good.Views);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case "rating":
                {
                    if (sorttype == "asc")
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderBy(good => good.Rating);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goods = rep.Goods.Select(x => x).Distinct().OrderByDescending(good => good.Rating);
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
        return PartialView(goods);
    }
}
```

Здесь происходит сортировка товаров по определённым критериям, которые задаются в select-option.

Вот код представления:

```
<section class="container">
<div class="dropdown">
    <select name="one" class="dropdown-select">
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по ID", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "id", sorttype = "asc" }, null)</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по имени", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "name", sorttype = "asc" }, null)</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по цене", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "price", sorttype = "asc" }, null)</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по кол-ву просмотров", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "views", sorttype = "asc" }, null)</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по рейтингу", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "rating", sorttype = "asc" }, null)</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="dropdown dropdown-dark">
    <select name="two" class="dropdown-select">
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по ID", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "id", sorttype = "desc" }, null)</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по имени", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "name", sorttype = "desc" }, null)</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по цене", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "price", sorttype = "desc" }, null)</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по кол-ву просмотров", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "views", sorttype = "desc" }, null)</option>
        <option>@Html.ActionLink("Сортировка по рейтингу", "Sort", "GoodsSort", new { fieldsort = "rating", sorttype = "desc" }, null)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Но при выборе из select-list сортировка не происходит, вообще програграмма никак не реагирует. Что я мог упустить?

Comment: `PartialView(goods.ToList())`?

Comment: Посмотрите вот [эту часть](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-5.0) руководства, как сделать поиск. Следует использовать класс SelectList.